# Winform4 C# using sql server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

```
frmCustomerDetails cd;
private void dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {               
        DataGridViewRow dr = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
        this.Hide();
        if (cd == null || cd.IsDisposed)
        {
            cd = new frmCustomerDetails();
            cd.MdiParent = new frmDairyManagementSystem();
            cd.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            cd.Show();
        }
        else
            cd.Activate();
        cd.txtCustomerID.Text = dr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        cd.dateTimePicker1.Text=dr.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtCustomerName.Text = dr.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        cd.grpGender.Text=dr.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtAddress.Text = dr.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtPhone.Text = dr.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtEmail.Text = dr.Cells[6].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtMobileNo.Text = dr.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
        cd.txtNotes.Text = dr.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
        cd.btnUpdate.Enabled = true;
        cd.btnDelete.Enabled = true;
        cd.btnSave.Enabled = false;
        cd.txtCustomerName.Focus();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

In my main form I have opened a child form using Mdi.

The child form's name is CustomerDetails. In that form if I want to Update or Delete already existing Customer, I have added a button in front of CustomerName. On click of that button a new form is opened, named CustomerRecord. In that form I have used DataGridView and I have written code to retrieve the data from database to it.

Now I want that if dataGridView1_RowHeaderMouseClick is clicked, I want to get the selected row on CustomerDetails form.

The dat is not going on my main form frmDairyManagementSystem.

One more issue is occuring that below dateTimePicker, grpGender is also not working.

This is my first project that I am doing as a project that I have to submit it to college.

It is not taking to my main form.

please help me as soon as possible

Comment: What's "not working" about it?

Comment: It's much more useful if you provide details about what's not working rather than just saying it "is not working". For example, do you get any errors or exceptions, have you tried stepping through the code with breakpoints?

Comment: if u don't know the answer then don't comment anything

Answer (score 0):

main form:

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    frmCustomersRecord rec = new frmCustomersRecord(this); 
    rec.ShowDialog();
    rec.GetData(); 
}
```

child form:

```
public partial class frmCustomersRecord : Form 
{
 public frmCustomersRecord()
    {
        //blank contructor (Instance of an class)
    }

    frmCustomerDetails cd;

    public frmCustomersRecord(frmCustomerDetails parentForm) : this()
    {
        this.cd = parentForm; 
    }    
    //call the methods using child form object
}
```